# Can I be hacked on lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, physical-access

I left my Windows PC for 10 minutes, but I locked it. Nobody knew my password.

Is it possible that someone with physical access for 10 minutes to a locked PC can access the computer without shutting it down? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

10 minutes gives an attacker a moderate amount of time. Not enough for all possible attacks, but certainly enough for *some*.

The most significant attack vector would be installation of malicious hardware, also known as a **Hotplug Attack**. Especially in an office setting, where cables are usually hidden away for aesthetical reasons, adding a device is unlikely to be noticed.

#### Network-based Attacks

The simplest attack is adding a tap between your ethernet port and computer. Right now, the connection between your computer and your router is more or less direct, ignoring switches:

```
┌──────────┐               ┌────────┐
│          │               │        │
│ Computer │◄─────────────►│ Router │
│          │               │        │
└──────────┘               └────────┘
```

However, by just adding a tap and another cable, it'd look like this:

```
             ┌──────────┐
             │ Attacker │
             └──────────┘
                   ▲
                   │
                   │
┌──────────┐     ┌─┴─┐     ┌────────┐
│          │     │ T │     │        │
│ Computer │◄───►│ a │◄───►│ Router │
│          │     │ p │     │        │
└──────────┘     └───┘     └────────┘
```

#### USB-based Attacks

Many computers have USB ports on the back, which are not regularly inspected. This allows an attacker to attach [USB-based devices](https://hak5.org/collections/sale/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe), which perform a variety of tasks, such as installing backdoors, stealing cached credentials or similar.

Depending on the size of the company, they might not even require you to leave. They can get in through the "smoker entrance", knock on your door, say they're from IT and have to quickly check your sockets since there was an issue. Then they crawl under your desk, add the tap with a lovely tape with "Do not remove!" added on. Most people would not protest, it's just human nature.

#### With more time...

You specifically stated that you left your computer unattended for roughly 10 minutes. However, if you left your computer unattended for longer, they may have been able to perform more tasks, such as cloning your entire hard drive/SSD including your TPM secret if it is configured to be in transparent mode (which, unfortunately, is more common than it should be).

The more time an attacker gets with your machine, the more damage they can do, including replacing internal hardware or planting malicious hardware inside your legitimate hardware (think: Keylogger inside your keyboard)

Comment: Can rubber ducky install a backdoor on a *locked* computer?

Comment: @nobody It can once unlocked

Comment: But how does it figure out when the computer gets unlocked? Does it just keep trying periodically?

Comment: @nobody It keeps trying periodically. Even if it just happens once per hour, that's fine.